# whats the amount of time that can be lft on a voice mail message

Tags: iphone

how long will voice mail record a message?  what is the amont of time you can leave a message on voice mail? 
I'm trying to find out how long of a message the I ohone can hold if there is a time limt then it cuts of ???? will it record for long periods of time

Comment: Isn't that up to the cellular provider?  I don't think iOS has a max length but I thought the recordings are done on the provider's system and then downloaded to your iPhone when you listen to them.

Answer (score 1):

Most mobile (cellular) phone providers only allow a max of 3mins. I know T-mobile, AT&T and Verizon all adhere to this and that's basically 80% of the market in the USA. Pretty much the same for Europe. Landlines with hardware answering machines are all different and can be user set.